# How to read file in pyspark from HDFS

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I have ingested data from mysql to hdfs using sqoop.

[image]
I want to read this file in pyspark .How can i read part_m_0000 and how can i find path of file in hdfs.

Comment: It would be useful if you could [edit] your question to include the commands as text, and show your Sqoop command, and show what you already tried in Spark

Answer (score 0):

Spark can (and should) read whole directories, if possible

> how can i find path of file in hdfs.

The path is `/user/root/etl_project`, as you've shown, and I'm sure is also in your Sqoop command

> How can i read part_m_0000

That would ultimately depend on what output format you told Sqoop to write to. You should prefer writing to Parquet files, which Spark has a native reader for.

```
spark.read.parquet("/user/root/etl_project")
```